# How do I get the current GPS location in Android?

Tags: java, android, gps

I have problem, I have one button and when I press button -> button.setOnclickListener -> I wil get the current GPS location . But when I don't press button and I want get location when my application is running, it false. I don't understand. 
This is code for button

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getAdd();
}
```

});

```
public void getAdd()
{
    Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

           Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        //  Location location = params[0];
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                        currentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (IOException exception1) {
                exception1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception2) {
                exception2.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String addressText = context.getString(
                        R.string.address_output_string,
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                                .getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getLocality(),
                        address.getCountryName());
                mAddress.setText(addressText);
            }
}
```

It true. But when i call getAdd() function when my application running. Textview mAddress.setText(addressText) false. If I press button , it will true.what can I do for get my address when application is running first time?

Comment: Run the getAdd() function in your onCreate() method?

Comment: yes, I want my textview setText my address when app running

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you wan the address to be displayed the first time you run the application, correct? One way to do that is to call the `getAdd()` function you created in your `onCreate()` function, in that way, when your application runs, the address will already be displayed in your textView.

Comment: yes, I want get address in my onCreate(), don't need press on button

Comment: help me :( I can't get address in my OnCreate()

Comment: just put `getAdd();` in onCreate(), preferably at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mMap.clear();
            if(!mProgress.isShowing())
            {
            mProgress.show();
            }
            LatLng lat=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mopt.position(lat);
            mopt.title("Loading...").snippet("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lat,14.0f));
            myMarker=mMap.addMarker(mopt);
            myMarker.showInfoWindow();

         new ReverseAddress(getBaseContext()).execute(lat);

        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {            
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {            
        }
    }
```

Use this method to get the current location also get changed current location.
To use this code use

```
//     Location Manager   
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                                    MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE, 
                                    MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                                    new MyLocationListener()
                    );
```